# How to get strings between two specific strings terms in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, web-scraping

good evening.

I would like help with how to get information between two strings in pandas (python).

Imagine that I have a database of car prices for each car dealer in which each cell had a text similar to this (note: the car dealer column can be the index of each row):

> "1 - Ford (1) - new:R$60000 / used:R$30000 sedan car 2 - Mercedes -
> Benz (1) - new:R$130000 / used:R$95000  silver sedan car  3 - Chery
> (caoa) (1) - new:R$80000 / used:R$60000 SUV car 5 - Others (1) -
> new:R$90000 / used:R$75500 hatch car"

[image: Dataset example]

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What do you want to do and what's the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Three step process

1. split whole string into line items using `re.split()`
2. parse out constituent parts of line using [pandas extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)
3. finally shape dataframe as wide...

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = "1 - Ford (1) - new:R$60000 / used:R$30000 sedan car 2 - Mercedes - Benz (1) - new:R$130000 / used:R$95000 silver sedan car 3 - Chery (caoa) (1) - new:R$80000 / used:R$60000 SUV car 5 - Others (1) - new:R$90000 / used:R$75500 hatch car"

# there as a car after "<n> - ".  split into lines
df = pd.DataFrame(re.split("[ ]?[0-9] - ", s)).replace("", np.nan).dropna()
# parse out each of the strings
df = df[0].str.extract("(?P<car>.*) \([0-9]\) - new:R\$(?P<new>[0-9]*) \/ used:R\$(?P<used>[0-9]*).*")

# finally format as wide format...
df = (df.melt().assign(car=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby("variable").cumcount(),
                col=lambda dfa: dfa.variable + (dfa.car+1).astype(str))
 .drop(columns=["variable","car"])
 .set_index("col")
 .T
)
```

|  | car1 | car2 | car3 | car4 | new1 | new2 | new3 | new4 | used1 | used2 | used3 | used4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value | Ford | Mercedes - Benz | Chery (caoa) | Others | 60000 | 130000 | 80000 | 90000 | 30000 | 95000 | 60000 | 75500 |

Answer (score 0):

You could use `extractall` to get a `multiIndex` dataframe that in summary will contain the dealer, the car number and the values extracted from regex named groups. After `extractall`, use `stack` to reshape the dataframe and the inner-most level index, this will allow you to set a new index with the format `[(dealer, carN)...]` and subsequently `groupby` that same first index level to keep the capturing order. Append each dealer data into a list and create the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    ["1 - Ford (1) - new:R$60000 / used:R$30000 sedan car 2 - Mercedes - Benz (1) - new:R$130000 / used:R$95000 silver sedan car 3 - Chery (caoa) (1) - new:R$80000 / used:R$60000 SUV car 5 - Others (1) - new:R$90000 / used:R$75500 hatch car",
    "2 - Toyota (1) - new:R$10543 / used:R$9020 silver sedan car",
    "3 - Honda (1) - new:R$123600 / used:R$34400 sedan car 2 - Fiat (1) - new:R$1955 / used:R$877 silver sedan car 3 - Cadillac (1) - new:R$174500 / used:R$12999 SUV car"])

regex = re.compile(
    r"\d\s-\s(?P<car>.*?)(?:\s\(\d+\)?\s)-\s"
    r"new:R\$(?P<new>[\d\.\,]+)\s/\s"
    r"used:R\$(?P<used>[\d\.\,]+).*?car"
)

df_out = df[0].str.extractall(regex).stack()

df_out.index = [df_out.index.get_level_values(0), \
                df_out.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[2]+str(x[1]+1)}')]

dealers = []
for n, g in df_out.groupby(level=0):
    dealers.append(g.droplevel(0))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dealers).rename_axis('Dealer')
print(df1)
```

Output from *df1*

```
          car1    new1  used1             car2    new2  used2          car3    new3  used3    car4   new4  used4
Dealer
0         Ford   60000  30000  Mercedes - Benz  130000  95000  Chery (caoa)   80000  60000  Others  90000  75500
1       Toyota   10543   9020              NaN     NaN    NaN           NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN
2        Honda  123600  34400             Fiat    1955    877      Cadillac  174500  12999     NaN    NaN    NaN
```